# YAML Variables, can you reference variables within variables?

Tags: variables, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using a variables.yml file as a template to store different variables, and I was curious if I am able to reference variables within the yml file itself to essentially nest them.

For example:

```
#variables.yml file
variables:
  food1:        'pineapple'
  food2:        'pizza'
  favoriteFood: '$(food1) $(food2)'
```

So that when I eventually call upon this variable "favoriteFood", I can just use ${{ variables.favoriteFood }} and the value should be "pineapple pizza"
Example:

```
#mainPipeline.yml file
variables: 
-  template: 'variables.yml'
steps: 
-  script: echo My favorite food is ${{ variables.favoriteFood }}.
```

Am I on the right track here? I can't seem to google to any examples of if this is possible.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Yes I did try it and thought it wasn't possible, but it is in fact possible as long as you follow the syntax i have above. I missed some values which is why it wasnt working. Fixed now!

Answer (score 3):

Yes! It is in fact possible, just follow the syntax outlined above. Don't forget spacing is critical in YML files.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example for your scenario from the official
`Learn`/`Azure`/`Azure DevOps`/`Azure Pipelines`/[Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops):

> ```
> variables:
>   staticVar: 'my value' # static variable
>   compileVar: ${{ variables.staticVar }} # compile time expression
>   isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')] # runtime expression
>
> steps:
>   - script: |
>       echo ${{variables.staticVar}} # outputs my value
>       echo $(compileVar) # outputs my value
>       echo $(isMain) # outputs True
> ```